# C# => JAVA: Filling a static ArrayList on declaration. Possible?

Tags: c#, java, list, arraylist

In my C# project I have a static List that gets filled immediately when declared.

```
  private static List<String> inputs = new List<String>()
        { "Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2"};
```

How would I do this in Java using the ArrayList?

I need to be able to access the values without creating a instance of the class.
Is it possible?

Comment: (You probably want to make the field `final`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by

> able to access the values without
>   creating a instance of the class

but the following snippet of code in Java has pretty much the same effect in Java as yours:

```
private static List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2");
```

Comment: As it is a static field, it really should be immutable. Unfortunately this adds to the verbosity. `private static final List<String> inputs = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2"));`. Should get list literals in JDK7.

Comment: Yay for the less verbose, later answer winning out? (No offense to you MAK. Just stating my perceived truth.)

Comment: @jdmichal: I think your answer was posted while I was still writing mine - otherwise I wouldn't have bothered to say the same thing again. I guess the slowest gun won :).

Comment: I often like to run `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` because `Arrays.asList()` doesn't produce a full implementation of `List` but `ArrayList` does. It's slightly slower if this has to be done repeatedly but if it's a one-shot deal then it's fine.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Double Brace Initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).
It looks like:

```
private static List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>()
  {{ add("Foo");
    add("Bar");
    add("Foo2");
    add("Bar2");
  }};
```

Comment: IMO This is the best answer, since it doesn't rely on helper class java.util.Arrays.

Comment: But it does create a somewhat hidden anonymous inner class. Subjective call on whether or not that is a better tradeoff.

Answer (score 7):

You can make static calls by enclosing them within static{} brackets like such:

```
private static final List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();

static {
  inputs.add("Foo");
  inputs.add("Bar");
  inputs.add("Foo2");
  inputs.add("Bar2");
}
```

Comment: That's nice, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need this to be an `ArrayList` specifically, or just a list?

Former:

```
private static java.util.List<String> inputs = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(
    java.util.Arrays.<String>asList("Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2"));
```

Latter:

```
private static java.util.List<String> inputs =
    java.util.Arrays.<String>asList("Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2");
```

[java.util.Arrays#asList(...) API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 3):

You may enjoy `ImmutableList` from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

`ImmutableList<String> inputs = ImmutableList.of("Foo", "Bar", "Foo2", "Bar2");`

The first half of [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM) discusses the immutable collections in great detail.